# Single Sign on entre aplicación web y Office365

Tags: asp.net, office365

Un cliente me pide implementar SSO entre su sitio web y Office 365.

Investigando, encuentro que Office autentica con Azure AD, por lo que entiendo el sitio web necesitaría usar el Passport de Microsoft como login, y de esa forma se implementaría el SSO. Pero esa solución queda descartada porque el cliente no quiere depender de Microsoft para autenticar a sus usuarios.

El cliente necesita que los usuarios sean autenticados con el login de su propio sitio, "mágicamente" esté logueado en Office.

Por las dudas investigo y encuentro en el sitio de Microsoft este texto

> Password-based Single Sign-On Configuring password-based single sign-on enables the users in your organization to be automatically
>   signed in to a third-party SaaS application by Azure AD using the user
>   account information from the third-party SaaS application. When you
>   enable this feature, Azure AD collects and securely stores the user
>   account information and the related password. Azure AD can support
>   password-based single sign on for any cloud-based app that has an
>   HTML-based sign-in page.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-appssoaccess-whatis

La pregunta concreta es ¿alguien hizo alguna vez algo así? Para mí es totalmente imposible que si la autoridad certificante es Microsoft, se pueda de alguna forma autenticar al usuario desde una aplicación de terceros, pero antes de decir "no se puede" quisiera una segunda opinión.

¿La solución sería instalar AD en el servidor local, federarlo con azure AD? Perdón pero los temas de infraestructura no son lo mío.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que tu mismo te estás respondiendo. Un cliente no te puede pedir usar servicios de un proveedor pero no depender de él. Es como si te pidiera también tener una línea de teléfono pero no depender de un enlace a la red que le presta servicio.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero supongamos que en el servidor de la empresa se instala AD, que a través de ADSF queda federado con Office 365(con Azure AD en realidad). Si los usuarios del sitio web son autenticados en el AD del sitio, podría al estar federado con Office enviarle las credenciales a Office? La documentación de Microsoft no es para nada clara al respecto

Comment: Supongo que son puntos de vista porque para mí esa solución sigue dependiendo de Microsoft.